# I am not able to load image on my html on django

Tags: django

I am not able to load my image on my template html.

Here is my code on models.py

```
class Userimgmodel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_img',blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

I have added the following in settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'mynotes/media')
```

Also in my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
     ....................//my paths//............

] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

And then in my template html

```
<img src= "{{ user.userimgmodel.profile_img.url }}" width="250" height="250">
```

I added the image from admin panel and saved it. I got the folder media created on my project and within it there was the folder profile_img where the image which was uploaded was also present.It was all good till now, but when I try to display it on m webpage using above code, all I get is a rectangle with no image.

Comment: when problems like this accure, go to the browser, rightclick on the element and hit "inspect element" you probably see a broken url, maybe this gives you a hint where django is looking for that image

Comment: I solved it. I forgot to add the line:                                                         urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)